# If $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $C([a, b])$, is it true that $\int u_n(x) dx \rightarrow \int u(x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

Let $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $C([a, b])$.Is it true that 
$$ \underset{a}{\overset{(a+b)/2}{\int}} u_n(x) dx \rightarrow \underset{a}{\overset{(a+b)/2}{\int}} u(x) dx ?$$

If $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $C([a, b])$ then $u_n(x) \rightarrow u(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. So, I think that
$$ \left|\underset{a}{\overset{(a+b)/2}{\int}} (u_n(x) - u(x)) dx  \hspace{8pt} \right| \rightarrow 0 $$
hence

$$ \underset{a}{\overset{(a+b)/2}{\int}} u_n(x) dx \rightarrow \underset{a}{\overset{(a+b)/2}{\int}} u(x) dx$$

Is it correct?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to use the norm of $C[a,b]$ in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the metric in $C([a,b])$ is the supremum metric so that
$$ \left| \int_a^{(a+b)2} u_n(t) \, dt - \int_a^{(a+b)2} u(t) \, dt \right| = 
\left| \int_a^{(a+b)2} u_n(t) - u(t) \, dt \right| \le \int_a^{(a+b)/2} |u_n(t) - u(t)| \, dt$$ and thus
$$ \left| \int_a^{(a+b)2} u_n(t) \, dt - \int_a^{(a+b)2} u(t) \, dt \right| \le \frac{b-a}{2} \max_{t \in [a,b]} |u_n(t) - u(t)| \to 0.$$

Comment: But $u_n$ and $u$ are continuous functions defined on the compact $[a, b]$ and so is $u_n(x) - u(x)$, and from Weierstrass theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) we have that this function attains the max and min